# PHP + Twilio + NGROK

Tags: php, twilio, cpanel, ngrok

I've come across an issue with "Click to Call" scripts by Twilio and it seems that while they are great for support, we can't get this issue resolved. Please have a look at the attached screen capture for full details. Error info below:

```
 [::1]:43544 [500]: POST /call.php - require(): Failed opening required
 '/home/oliver/public_htm/srcvendor/autoload.php'
 (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/share/pear') in
 /home/oliver/public_htm/src/call.php on line 2
```

Any other suggestions? Line 2 in call.php makes reference to

```
require __DIR__ . 'vendor/autoload.php'
```

[image]

Comment: Please use the formatting to make your question more readable.

Comment: You are missing a `/` between `DIR` and `vendor/autoload.php` - or more likely one directory before using `..`.

Comment: Can you share a link to the click to call script you are referencing?